# How to Prove It - Ch2 Sec 2 Exercise 2a

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

**Question:** I am uncertain if my initial formulation of the logical form of the below statement is correct.

**How to Prove It (Velleman) Chapter 2, Section 2, Exercise 2a**

> > Negate these statements and then reexpress the results as equivalent positive statements. *(it is implied that you put into logical form first based on worked examples in the chapter)*
> >
> > 2(a) "There is someone in the freshman class who doesn't have a roommate."

I have written this (prior to negation)

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\exists x[F(x) \rightarrow \forall y \neg R(x,y)]
\\ \\
F(x): \text{x is in the freshman class}\\
R(x, y): \text{x is roommates with y}\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}$$

I thought this was the correct formulation however, I found two blogs online that formulate the phrase as follows (again, before negation)

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\exists x[F(x) \wedge \neg\exists yR(x,y)]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}$$

I checked to make sure equations (1) and (2) are not equivalent

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\exists x[F(x) \rightarrow \forall y \neg R(x,y)] \qquad &\text{(1)}\\
\exists x[F(x) \rightarrow \neg \exists yR(x,y)] \qquad &\text{quantifier negation}\\
\exists x[\neg F(x) \vee \neg \exists yR(x,y)] \qquad &\text{conditional law}\\
\exists x\neg[F(x) \wedge \exists yR(x,y)] \qquad &\text{DeMorgans}\\
\neg\forall x[F(x) \wedge \exists yR(x,y)] \qquad &\text{quantifier negation}\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

I am trying to convince myself that (2) is correct, but can't see why (1) is incorrect. Is it because it's somewhat speculative ("There exists someone x, where **if** that person x is a freshman then for all people y, person x and person y are not roommates") vs declarative ("There **is** someone who is a freshman and for all people y, that person and person y are not roommates")?

Comment: Since you can push the $\neg$ in turning $\neg\exists y$ into $\forall y\neg$, it's worth noting that the only difference between (1) and (2) is $\to$ versus $\land$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite correct in your final paragraph, but perhaps could do with a more concrete argument? Consider a sophomore, say. They're not a freshman. So in fact they satisfy equation (1) - the implication holds true trivially because they are not a freshman at all! That is why (2) is the correct formulation - (1) allows the sophomore. (How many roommates they have doesn't matter at all!)

EDIT: Perhaps I could be clearer. Your equation (1) says 'there exists a student who, if they are a freshman, must not have any roommates'. My point is that a sophomore satisfies this condition, and so this does not correspond to the logical statement you were aiming for.

Comment: ah I think I'm seeing that now. I got turned down the path of using the conditional based on a worked example that read very similarly. I see now that was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This year every freshman has a roommate.
Dan, it so happens, is not a freshman.
If he were a freshman, he wouldn't have a roommate.
Thusly Dan satisfies your statement even though
there is no freshman without a roommate.

Answer (score 0):

Universal quantifiers are restricted by a conditional; existential quantifiers are restricted by *conjunction*".    Thus you use form (2), as follows.

> "There is someone in the freshman class who doesn't have a roommate."

That is to say: "There exists a person, who, is in the freshman class *and* does not have a roommate."

$$\exists x~(F(x)\land \lnot\exists y~R(x,y))$$

Comment: It would probably be more pedagogically beneficial to also give some explanation or argument as to *why* the quantifiers are restricted that way. I suspect the OP ended up with their incorrect formula in part *because* they applied "rules" that they hadn't thought deeply about.

Comment: @Graham Kemp -  I had not been introduced to the concept of restricted quantifiers and their equivalences. Very helpful.